# Get time in other cities given a city to start

Tags: php, time, gmt

Suppose I have a given city (eg. Milan) with a given time (which I write), and I need to know the time in other city (suppose New York and Tokyo), how can I accomplish this in code (the cities will be always the same, so... an array)?

Comment: For this you will require to do some math

Comment: Yeah. You'll need an enormous array or a database with the timezone of every other city. Then you'll get the current time and calculate the timezones.

Comment: the city will be 10-20, no more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ts = new DateTime('2016-11-17 11:39:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$ts->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

echo $ts->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

That's all you need to do. You just need to make sure you're using one of [the defined timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php). If you have any cities not in this list, you need to map them to the appropriate timezone they're in, like Milan → Europe/Rome.